# Generic circular buffer implementation in C++

Tags: c++, circular-buffer

I started writing my circular buffer library, just for fun. I came across a particular problem:

```
template < class T >
T CircularBuffer<T>::pop()
```

it returns the type T, but what about the case when the CB is empty, and the user tries to use pop()? Returning a nullptr makes no sense, because nullptr can't be converted to double for instance. Obviously, the exception can be thrown, but is there a more semantically friendly way to do it?

Edit: By "semantically friendly" I mean this:

When pushing in a full CB, it is only natural to throw an exception. Exception should prevent the program from crashing, because there is not enough memory for the new element. Throwing an exception when popping an empty CB seems off to me, semantically, because program is not about to crash. But if it is the only option available, tell me.

Comment: There's nothing semantically unfriendly about throwing exceptions. But perhaps try to divide `pop` into `pop` and `top`. Thus it could become a noop, while `top` realistically throws. It also removes the need to copy on removal, which is always nice.

Comment: _"Obviously, the exception can be thrown, but is there a more semantically friendly way to do it?"_ What do you mean _semantically friendly_. Throwing an exception is probably the only valid semantcs. Also you should take a lookk how `std::queue` solved the problem. The `pop()` function returns `void` and the topmost element is accessed through `front()`.

Comment: This is one of the uses to which `std::optional` could be put, if you're using a compiler that supports the latest C++2017 standard library.

Comment: Return codes solution: `Status pop(T& out);` Where `Status` is a type that reports the status of the call to the caller: error, success, empty, out of memory etc. For convenience you can make `Status` to be convertible to `bool` and to also provide a plain text description of the error. In any case, whether you choose return codes, exceptions or other means of error handling, implement it consistently across the library code and don't mix them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) or [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) - they are classes which store a value *or* an empty state.

You can change your signature to:

```
template < class T >
std::optional<T> CircularBuffer<T>::pop()
```

And your contract will be something along the lines of:

- If the buffer is empty, `std::nullopt` will be returned.
- Otherwise, a non-empty `std::optional<T>` containing the head element will be returned.

---

Alternatively, consider taking an a "continuation" function that will only be invoked if the pop was successful. Example:

```
template < class F >
decltype(auto) CircularBuffer<T>::pop(F&& continuation);
```

Usage:

```
some_circular_buffer.pop([](auto popped_item)
{
    // I will only be called if the pop was successful.
});
```

You can extend this concept by also taking an additional continuation for the "pop failure" case.